# JSONException: End of input at character 0

Tags: android, json

I'm facing the error as given in the logs below. The error says that the return code which is passed is 0. I can successfully receive the OPT via my email and when I enter it and press confirm registration there's the toast error message I get `Unable to generate valid response for registration. Try again`. I don't understand exactly why this is happening.

> Error:

Comment: post your json in which your getting error

Comment: Why are you parsing json from errorMsg?
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(errorMsg);

What is diff b/w errorMsg & urlPart?

Answer (score 1):

your json response is not correct.

Set response this way:

```
{"serviceName":"register",
"emailID":"aditi.shrivastava@allianz.com",
"token":"728962"}
```

Comment: The above is the method I have written for registering with token.

Comment: I tried using above response but it give me an error as "W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for retCode". Any help on this?

Comment: retCode key is not available in above response

Answer (score 1):

Check your backend API because a token isn't received from API.

token not null but the response is empty.